# Timespan function to convert minutes into 8 hour working days

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

Need to count in C# app, minutes in SLA to show in format :

```
N working days, N working hours, N working minutes
```

current code show up only hours:minutes format:

```
TimeSpan spWorkMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(12534);
string workHours = string.Format("{0}:{1:00}", (int)spWorkMin.TotalHours, spWorkMin.Minutes);
Console.WriteLine(workHours);
```

Comment: Why this snippet doesn't use TimeSpan.Days is impossible to guess.  Use Hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to show the timespan in number of days, hours, minutes:

```
TimeSpan spWorkMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(12534);
string workHours = $"{spWorkMin.Days} working days, {spWorkMin.Hours} working hours, {spWorkMin.Minutes} working minutes";
Console.WriteLine(workHours);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but in every usual day, you get 3 business days.

```
var numberOfDays = minutes/60/24;
var numberOfBusinessDays = numberOfDays/3;
var numberOfBusinessHours = (numberOfBusinessDays - Math.Truncate(numberOfBusinessDays))*24;
var numberOfBusinessMinutes = (numberOfBusinessHours - Math.Truncate(numberOfBusinessHours)*60;
```

Then you can truncate decimal part from all of the results

```
int numberOfBusinessDaysToInt = Math.Truncate(numberOfBusinessDays);
int numberOfBusinessHoursToInt = Math.Truncate(numberOfBusinessHours);
int numberOfBusinessMinutesToInt = Math.Truncate(numberOfBusinessMinutes);
```